# VPN PPTP connection fails

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I am trying to connect to a PPTP VPN on my Ubuntu 10.10 computer but it seems to fail.
I have tried successfully to connect to the VPN on a OS X machine and it did work.

I connect using the NetworkManager applet and the VPN seems to think that I am connected for a while before it closes down again and tells me that the connection fails.

When I look in my /var/log/syslog this is what I find:

```
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp'...  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 3415  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' appeared, activating connections  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN connection 'anonine' (Connect) reply received.  
Clio pppd[3417]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.  
Clio pppd[3417]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.  Clio modem-manager: (net/ppp0): could not get port's parent device  
Clio pppd[3417]: Using interface ppp0  
Clio pppd[3417]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2  
Clio pptp[3420]: nm-pptp-service-3415 log[main:pptp.c:276]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated  
Clio pptp[3431]: nm-pptp-service-3415 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'  
Clio pptp[3431]: nm-pptp-service-3415 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:738]: Received Start Control Connection Reply  
Clio pptp[3431]: nm-pptp-service-3415 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:772]: Client connection established.  
Clio pptp[3431]: nm-pptp-service-3415 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'  
Clio pptp[3431]: nm-pptp-service-3415 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:857]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.  
Clio pptp[3431]: nm-pptp-service-3415 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:896]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 29301).  
Clio pppd[3417]: CHAP authentication succeeded  
Clio pppd[3417]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled  
Clio pppd[3417]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP  
Clio pppd[3417]: local  IP address   [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio pppd[3417]: remote IP address   [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio pppd[3417]: primary   DNS address   [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio pppd[3417]: secondary DNS address   [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN connection 'anonine' (IP Config Get) reply received.      
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN Gateway:  [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Tunnel Device: ppp0  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Internal IP4 Address:   [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Internal IP4 Prefix: 32  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Internal IP4 Point-to-Point Address:  [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Internal IP4 DNS:   [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Internal IP4 DNS:   [AN IP ADRESS]  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> DNS Domain: '(none)'  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN connection 'anonine' (IP Config Get) complete.  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> Policy set 'anonine' (ppp0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.  
Clio NetworkManager[1208]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 4  
Clio nm-dispatcher.action: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status 1.
```

Thus it seems to be able to connect to the VPN but encounters some sort of problem when invoking the script:

> Clio nm-dispatcher.action: Script
>   '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status
>   1.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!